# How to populate an array parameter in a Spotfire URL configurationBlock

Tags: spotfire

So...I managed to create a URL which populates a parameterised information link.

```
https://myserver-prod.mycompany.net/SpotfireWeb/ViewAnalysis.aspx?file=/Reports/02_Testing/Hyperlink_Parameter_Test&configurationBlock=pCountry%3D%22GERMANY%22%3B
```

This passes in GERMANY to the pCountry parameter and is working fine.

However, I am not sure how I would push in an array of values.  I have changed my parameter to be an array, and am trying different things but they are not working.

This documentation isn't great in this respect.

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/create-configuration-block-tibco-spotfire

I have tried things like this, where I am comma separating the parameters (here I am passing in GERMANY and FRANCE separated by a url encoded comma (%3B).

```
https://spotfireweb-prod.rd.astrazeneca.net/SpotfireWeb/ViewAnalysis.aspx?file=/GMD/GRAPSQA/ARIEL/Reports/02_Testing/Hyperlink_Parameter_Test_Array&configurationBlock=pCountry%3D%22GERMANY%3BFRANCE%22%3B
```

Answer (score 1):

A list parameter has the following syntax:

```
COUNTRY={"GERMANY","FRANCE"};
```

Used in a URL it must be encoded: `COUNTRY%3D%7B%22GERMANY%22%2C%22FRANCE%22%7D`

Learn more about configuration blocks here: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/create-configuration-block-tibco-spotfire

Comment: Hi, thanks, although this doesn't work - it doesn't even transfer the values to a document property with the same name in a text area, as it does with a single value.  I have defined the parameter as an array parameter.

Comment: it looks like you've left off the curly braces in the example URL you provided. can you double check that your URL looks exactly like the suggestion @mrylande posted and report back?